# Fonts in Abstract

Tags: abstract

I am using AMS Latex Article template and I have this problem: The word "ABSTRACT" in the abstract section is, by default, all capitalized and not bold. I want to change that to bold and capitalize only the first letter of the word abtract. Can anyone help please?

```
\documentclass[timesroman11pt, reqno]{amsart} 
\renewcommand\abstractname{\textbf{Abstract}} \usepackage[left=1.1in,top=1in,right=1.1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{mathptm} 
\makeatletter 
\def\specialsection{\@startsection{section}{1}% 
\z@{\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}% 
% {\normalfont\centering}}% DELETED 
{\normalfont}}% NEW 
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}% \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}% 
% {\normalfont\scshape\centering}} % DELETED 
{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}}% NEW 
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4):

Many document classes store standard section names such as `Abstract` and `References` in variables with names such as `\abstractname` and `\refname`. Often you just have to change their definition.

```
\renewcommand\abstractname{\textbf{Abstract}}
```

However, in this case things are slightly more complicated, because [amsart.cls](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart) uses

```
\scshape\abstractname
```

to typeset the heading for the abstract. I think it's true to say that in the default font, there are no bold small capitals, so in

```
\scshape\textbf{\abstractname}
```

the `\scshape` gets ignored, and the above `\renewcommand` works as intended. However, if you load a font that does have these glyphs (e.g. with `\usepackage{mathptmx}`) then 'Abstract' will end up capitalised. To prevent this, you can use the [etoolbox package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etooolbox) to get rid of `\scshape` entirely, and replace it with `\textbf`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\patchcmd{\abstract}{\scshape\abstractname}{\textbf{\abstractname}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\author{A Mathematician}
\title{A nice paper}
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I try your suggestion and it fixes one part of the problem. The word Abstract is now bold but it still capitalizes the whole word abstract. I only need the first letter, i.e., letter "A", in the word abstract to be capitalized. Can you point out what I should do next?

Comment: @Lawrence --- strange. Only `A` is capitalised when I compile the above code on my machine. What version of `amsart.cls` are you using?

Comment: I use the latest version. It is strange because when I enter your code just by itself, it comes out right but when I incorporate it into my template, it capitalizes the whole word abstract. My be something in my template interfere with it. Below is the top part of my template

Comment: In that case, you need to edit your question and add a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: \documentclass[timesroman11pt, reqno]{amsart}
\renewcommand\abstractname{\textbf{Abstract}} 
\usepackage[left=1.1in,top=1in,right=1.1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptm}
\makeatletter
\def\specialsection{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
%  {\normalfont\centering}}% DELETED
  {\normalfont}}% NEW
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
%  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}% DELETED
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Large}}% NEW
\makeatother

Comment: If I remove \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptm} from above, then it comes out right!

Comment: As soon as I add \usepackage{times} back in, it capitalizes the whole word abstract again!

Comment: So now I have two problems, to get the word abstract in the right form, i.e. only the letter A is capitalized, then it is in the wrong font (not times or times Roman). To get the right font, the word abstract will be in the wrong form (all letters in the word abstract are capitalized).

Comment: @Lawrence --- I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the definition of the `abstract` environment in `amsart` shows that the treatment of the abstract label is hard coded to use `\scshape`.

```
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
...
 \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape\abstractname.]%
...
```

To override the intended behavior you need `\abstractname` to include a different font shape (e.g., `\upshape`). Something like `\def\abstractname{\upshape\bfseries Abstract}` should work.